# Angular: How to catch event when user clicks outside of bootstrap modal dialog?

Tags: angular

How to catch event when user clicks outside of bootstrap modal dialog?

```
<!-- MODAL ZOOM  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="itinerary" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-large-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">                      
                  <div class="modal-body">    
                        BODY    
                  </div>    
            </div>
      </div>
</div>

<!-- /MOLDA ZOOM -->
```

Comment: are you using plain Bootstrap or some other binding like ng-bootstrap ?? maybe also create a [mcve] would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions proposed didn't work for me,  I found a workarond: don't allow to the user to close the modal page when he clicks outside. just adding these properties **data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"**

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"  id="idmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-large-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">                      
              <div class="modal-body">    
                    BODY    
              </div>    
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside) as below. Just put the `clickOutside` event in the tag of which outside you want to catch the click outside event.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="itinerary" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-large-label" (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside()">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">                      
              <div class="modal-body">    
                    BODY    
              </div>    
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My working solution was to define the callback as an input for Modal and call it on destroy.

Modal open Component

```
const modalRef = this._modal.open(MyComponent, options);
modalRef.componentInstance.afterClose = (response) => {
   // desired code here.
}
```

MyComponent implements OnDestroy

```
@Input() afterClose: Function; // called after modal is closed.
constructor() {}
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.afterClose(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
@ViewChild('modal') modal: ElementRef;    
 ngAfterViewInit() {
     document.addEventListener('click', this.checkIfClickedInside, true);
 }

 checkIfClickedInside = (event: Event) => {
   let isClickInside = this.modal.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
   if (!isClickInside) console.log('clicked outside);
 };
```

Comment: in general using `addEventListener` is not a good practice. way better to use `rxjs` `fromEvent()`

Comment: @MassimoCosta can you provide a documentation for it ? I actually didn't know about it, and thanks in advance.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined   ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I referenced my modal with #editModal in HTML file. Then in TypeScript file I reached my modal with @ViewChild. I listened to click event of my modal, executed my handler method on click event. Modal has got className property. I made condition upon it, according to the condition I recognized when user clicks outside of the bootstrap modal. Then I wrote code for things to be done when user clicks outside of the model.

.html

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  #editModal
  (click)="onModalClick()"
  tabindex="-1"
  id="myModal"
  *ngIf="showEditModal"
> ... </div>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('editModal') editModalRef!: ElementRef;

.
.
.

onModalClick() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (
        this.editModalRef.nativeElement.className ===
        'modal fade ng-star-inserted'
      ) {
        this.showEditModal = false;
        console.log('closed');
      }
    });
  }
```